# Change Google Chart Timeline bar color according boolean condition from data table

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

My dataTable has 6 columns. Column 5 is boolean. I would like to color the bars according to the column 2 as I already did, however if column 5 is false, color should be grey (no matter the string in column 2).

I tried to use " dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'boolean', role: 'scope' });"
But it does not work with Timelines. I also tried to send string with the color for each bar in column 5 but it also did not work.

Could you please help me with this?

```js
 var timeLineGraph = 'timeLineGraph';

var arrayDataTimeline  = [
 [ 'Debora',  'Pharmacist', 1,   new Date(2017,2,1,06,0,0),  new Date(2017,2,1,11,0,0), true],
      [ 'Debora',  'Pharmacist', 1,    new Date(2017,2,1,12,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,15,0,0), true],
      [ 'Gabriela',  'Pharmacist', 2,  new Date(2017,2,1,07,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,13,0,0), false ],
      [ 'Gabriela',  'Pharmacist',2,      new Date(2017,2,1,14,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,16,0,0), false],
      [ 'Andrieli', 'Teller', 3,      new Date(2017,2,1,15,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,18,0,0), true],
      [ 'Andrieli',  'Teller', 3,      new Date(2017,2,1,19,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,24,0,0), true],
      [ 'Alex', 'Teller', 4,      new Date(2017,2,1,15,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,18,0,0), true],
      [ 'Alex', 'Teller', 4,      new Date(2017,2,1,19,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,24,0,0),true]];
   

google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  
  function drawTimeline(timeLineGraph, arrayDataTimeline) {

    var container = document.getElementById(timeLineGraph);
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    
     
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Nome'});
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Cargo' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: 'id' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Começo' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Fim' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'boolean', role: 'scope' });
    
    
    dataTable.addRows(arrayDataTimeline);

    
  
 
  
  
    var options = {
      showBarLabels: false,
      groupByRowLabel: true, // novo
      
        rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'sans-serif'},
       hAxis: {
            format: 'HH:mm'
   }
  
    };
    
  }

drawTimeline(timeLineGraph, arrayDataTimeline);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<html>
  
  <head>
    </head>
  
  <body>

<div id="timeLineGraph" style="height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>
  
  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**, when drawing the chart, the data table must match the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#data-format)

which is why adding the *boolean* column doesn't work

to keep the *boolean* column, use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to hide it from the chart...

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
dataView.hideColumns([5]);
```

then use the `dataView` to draw the chart

```
chart.draw(dataView, options);
```

---

**next**, since there are no standard options to color a bar, "one off" from the rest

the color can be changed manually with script, once the chart's `'ready'` event fires

however, on any *interactivity*, the chart will revert the bars back to their original colors
such as select, mouse over, etc...

to force the chart to keep the new color,
use a `MutationObserver` to know when the chart has *interactivity*,
and change the bar to the desired color

---

**finally**, to find the bars to change,
look through the `<rect>` elements created by the chart

the timeline bars (`<rect>` elements) will have an `'x'` attribute greater than zero
also, the order of the elements in the dom, will follow the order of the rows in the data table
so once the first bar is found, it will relate back to the first row in the data table, and so on...

however, separate bars are drawn when the mouse hovers the bar, for highlighting

these equate to extra bars, and will not have a relation back to the data table

as such, when the `'ready'` event fires, find the bars and save the coordinates to an array

then in the `MutationObserver`, if a bar is found that matches the coordinates saved in the array, change the color

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var timeLineGraph = 'timeLineGraph';

    var arrayDataTimeline  = [
      ['Debora', 'Pharmacist', 1, new Date(2017,2,1,06,0,0), new Date(2017,2,1,11,0,0), true],
      ['Debora', 'Pharmacist', 1, new Date(2017,2,1,12,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,15,0,0), true],
      ['Gabriela', 'Pharmacist', 2, new Date(2017,2,1,07,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,13,0,0), false],
      ['Gabriela', 'Pharmacist',2, new Date(2017,2,1,14,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,16,0,0), false],
      ['Andrieli', 'Teller', 3, new Date(2017,2,1,15,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,18,0,0), true],
      ['Andrieli', 'Teller', 3, new Date(2017,2,1,19,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,24,0,0), true],
      ['Alex', 'Teller', 4, new Date(2017,2,1,15,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,18,0,0), true],
      ['Alex', 'Teller', 4, new Date(2017,2,1,19,00,0), new Date(2017,2,1,24,0,0),true]
    ];
    drawTimeline(timeLineGraph, arrayDataTimeline);
  },
  packages:['timeline']
});

function drawTimeline(timeLineGraph, arrayDataTimeline) {
  var container = document.getElementById(timeLineGraph);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Nome'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'Cargo'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'id'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Começo'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Fim'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'boolean', role: 'scope'});
  dataTable.addRows(arrayDataTimeline);

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
  dataView.hideColumns([5]);

  var options = {
    showBarLabels: false,
    groupByRowLabel: true,
    rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'sans-serif'},
    hAxis: {
      format: 'HH:mm'
    }
  };

  var observer = new MutationObserver(setScope);

  var outOfScope = [];
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rowIndex = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (bar) {
      if (parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x')) > 0) {
        if (!dataTable.getValue(rowIndex, 5)) {
          bar.setAttribute('fill', '#9e9e9e');
          outOfScope.push([
            bar.getAttribute('x'),
            bar.getAttribute('y')
          ]);
        }
        rowIndex++;
      }
    });

    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function setScope() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (bar) {
      outOfScope.forEach(function (coords) {
        if ((bar.getAttribute('x') === coords[0]) && (bar.getAttribute('y') === coords[1])) {
          bar.setAttribute('fill', '#9e9e9e');
        }
      });
    });
  }

  chart.draw(dataView, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeLineGraph"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks a lot WhiteHat!

Comment: Do you mean up vote? I tried it already. However, I do not have enough reputation in stackoverflow to give you an up vote. :/